# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKUserLocation tag]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

i just compare two values but sometime app crash. How to handle it.

```
NSString *  markerid = [_selectedCoordinate objectForKey:@"markerid"];
    for(CustomAnnotations *annotation in _mapView.annotations){
        if(annotation.tag == [markerid integerValue]){
            [_mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:NO];
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i run code in viewWillAppear.

Comment: put a breakpoint to it...

Comment: Exception breakpoint, to be specific.

Comment: One/many/all `annotation` is an object of class `MKUserLocation` not of `CustomAnnoation` that's why it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map annotations contains the user location annotations as well, either check `[annotation class] != [MKUserLocation class]` or `[annotation class] == [CustomAnnoation class]` then get the tag of the annotation

```
NSString *  markerid = [_selectedCoordinate objectForKey:@"markerid"];
for(CustomAnnotations *annotation in _mapView.annotations){
    if([annotation class] != [MKUserLocation class]) {
        if(annotation.tag == [markerid integerValue]) {
            [_mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:NO];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```